# chrome ext many loads on update page

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

In app use content script for all pages, and send message to active page on complete loaded page, but I have many calls of script sometimes 2 and more:

[You can see that here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLh02.jpg)

Code implimentation:

```
chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener(function (tabs) {
   chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
        if(changeInfo.status === "complete") {

                    let tabid = tab.id;

                    console.log("Site is valid: url -> " + tab.url)

                    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
                        file: '/injections/mobile.bet365.com.js',
                    });

                    console.log(tab);

                    setTimeout(function () {
                        console.log("timeout was set")

                        chrome.tabs.query({}, function (tabs) {

                            let countOpenedTabsFrom = tabs.length;
                            let opener = 1;

                            // на целевой вкладке
                            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabid, {
                                message: "start_app",
                                opener: opener,
                                queuenumber: countOpenedTabsFrom
                            }, function (response) {
                                console.log(response);
                            });
                        });
                    }, 500);
                }
```

And executed script have many queries too.
Why is this happen?

Comment: onUpdated listener is also invoked for title, favicon, and so on. Simply check changeInfo.status === 'complete'

Comment: @wOxxOm, yes it is present in code maybe I copied not all

Comment: Currently you add a new onUpdated listener every time a new tab is created. Either move `onUpdated.addListener` outside of onCreated or reuse the same global function as a listener.

Answer (score 0):

Every time `onCreated` event fires, you're adding a *new* `onUpdated` listener.

When, after that, `onUpdated` event fires, *all of them* are executed, leading to the behavior you're seeing.

You either need to de-register the handlers when they are done, or register the handler only once. See [`chrome.events` docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/events) (which describe common points of all event objects in other APIs) for ideas on how to implement that.

Note that the code inside `chrome.tabs.onCreated` listener does not use the `tabs` parameter at all, so it's not clear why do you even need to listen to `onCreated`.